# Conversion of class instance to raw byte array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, object, serialization, byte

I'm making a Human-machine-interface application in C# where serial port communication needs to be set between an application and STM32 based robot controller.
But since that controller is C++ based I need to convert communication objects to byte arrays and then send it out.
I tried class serialization but doesn't work because it generates much bigger data (445 Bytes) array and positions of variables don't match so c++ code on is unable to parse it correctly.

Here is my class that needs to be sent to robot:

```
    [Serializable]
    public class RobotData
    {
        public RobotData(Byte _axisCount)
        {
            axisCount = _axisCount;
            axData = new AxisData[axisCount];

            for (int i = 0; i < axisCount; i++)
            {
                axData[i] = new AxisData((Byte)i);
            }

        }

        public Int16 messageType;
        public Byte axisCount;
        public Int32 statusDWord;
        public AxisData[] axData;

    }
```

And here is definition of the inner class:

```
    public class AxisData
    {
        public AxisData(Byte _axisId)
        {
            axisId = _axisId;
        }

        public Byte axisId;
        public Int32 position;
        public float velocity ;
        public float acceleration;
        public float torque;

    }
```

So I'm trying to create a byte array where it'll go like this:

**- position / variable**

- 0        / messageType
- 2        / axisCount
- 3        / statusDWord
- 7        / axData[0].axisId
- 8        / axData[0].position
- ...
- 54       / axData[2].torque

(total size is 58 bytes)

Is there some universal way (that work with any class) that creates this pure raw data array?
And how could be the incoming data bytes constructed into a similar class?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do other fancy stuff, though why not just control the *serialization* yourself with [`BinaryWriter.Write`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.binarywriter.write?view=netframework-4.8) overloads.

```
public class RobotData
{
   ...

   public byte[] ToArray()
   {
      using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
         using (var sw = new BinaryWriter(ms))
         {
            sw.Write(messageType);
            sw.Write(axisCount);
            sw.Write(statusDWord);

            foreach (var data in axData)
            {
               sw.Write(data.axisId);
               sw.Write(data.position);
               ...
            }

            return ms.ToArray();
         }
   }
}
```

Comment: Is there some similar way to deserialize byte array into the object?

Comment: @BranislavBaran yes basically the same thing in reverse. Check out the [`BinaryReader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.binaryreader?view=netframework-4.8) Methods. it has everything there for you

Comment: Yes, works great either. Thanks pal! I'm so happy to have it working finally.